# How does the order of an element of $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ correspond to its trace?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace

Suppose $g$ is a diagonalizable element of $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ (we call an element of $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ diagonalizable, iff it has two linearly independent eigenvectors). Then the order of $g$ is the Least Common Multiple of orders of its eigenvalues $e_1$ and $e_2$ (they lie in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$, "order of a field element $x$" stands for the minimal natural $n$, such that $x^n = 1$). However, as $det(g) = 1$, $e_1e_2 = 1$. That means, that orders of the eigenvalues of $g$ are equal (and thus equal to the order of $g$). Also, it is easy to notice, that $x$ is an eigenvalue of $g$ iff it satisfies the equality $x^2 - tr(g)x + 1 = 0$. So one can conclude, that the order of any diagonalizable element of $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ depends solely on its trace. So there exists a function $f$ from $\mathbb{F}_p$ to $\mathbb{N}$, such that $f(x)$ is order of any diagonalizable element of $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ with trace $x$. The question is: how to write the function $f$ in a closed form?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's the order in ${\mathbb F}_{p^2}$ of $u + \sqrt{u^2-1}$, where $u = {\rm tr}(g)/2$. Orders of elements in finite fields do not have any easily described pattern. I don't believe that there is any particular relationship between the orders of $x$ and of $x+1$ for elements $x$ in finite fields.

Comment: Surely not every element of $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a possible trace of a diagonalisable element? If $2t$ is the trace we need $\sqrt{t^2-1}$ to exist in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician He probably means diagonalizable over a splitting field, which in this case could be  ${\mathbb F}_{p^2}$.

Comment: Agreed, @DerekHolt, but he explicitly says two LI eigenvectors without saying he's changing the field.

Comment: Sorry, another comment/query. You ask for $f$ "in closed form", but I think you in fact want more than that. I'd say that $f(u)=\text{min}\{k\in\{1,2,…,p^2−1\}|(C(X^2−uX+1))^k=I\}$ is closed form, just not very illuminating. [Here $C(p(X))$ is the companion matrix.]